# Help with htaccess and two Wordpress instances

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old legacy application, written in php. It's going to be replaced by two Wordpress instances, one being the website itself and the other being a blog (I have to use them separated as two instances). So I'm going to have a dir for this old version, a dir for the site and a dir for the blog.

This is my situation **now**:

Suppose my app url is `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/` and my dir structure is as follows:

```
..htdocs/old_site/
    files.php
    files.css
    blog/
        wordpress files
```

I'm terrible at htaccess. So, since `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/` is pointing to `htdocs/old_site/`, writing `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/blog/` goes to `htdocs/old_site/blog/`. So my solution was to create a dir named blog instead of a .htaccess solution to redirect.

I want a more professional solution. I would like my dir structure to be:

```
..htdocs/
    old_site/
    site/
    blog/
```

So, `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/` would go to `htdocs/site/`, and `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/blog/` to `htdocs/blog/`. I would like to know how to create an `.htaccess` on `htdocs/` to accomplish this. In the end I need to have 3 .htaccess:

`htdocs/.htaccess` with this configuration (knowing to which dir it's going to go), manually made by me with your help
`htdocs/site/.htaccess` again, but with site wordpress instance configuration, made automatically by wordpress
`htdocs/blog/.htaccess`, but with blog wordpress instance configuration, made automatically by wordpress

Comment: I'm tempted to give +1 just for the user name. :)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a single WP install to power both the pages and the blog? Have you read  http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: is, believe me. Duplicating code is bad, but the two installations have completely different layouts and logic, and trying to create conditionals in one theme it was going to be really difficult and create a mess.

Comment: that's fair play - just checking in case you weren't aware of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want this, right?

```
http://www.example.com/          --> /htdocs/site/
http://www.example.com/blog/     --> /htdocs/blog/
http://www.example.com/old_site/ --> /htdocs/old_site/
```

If so, you can try this...

**/htdocs/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/$0
```

**/htdocs/site/.htaccess** (What WordPress should do + a little extra):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Prevent people from going to /site/ directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/site [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**/htdocs/blog/.htaccess** (What WordPress should do):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I've edited my question: "So, `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/` would go to `htdocs/site/`, and `http://www.mywebsiteurltest.com/blog/` to `htdocs/blog/`."

Comment: Yeah, that's what this should do (although maybe you don't want to be able to access old_site at all, I wasn't sure about that). Does it not work, or?

Comment: It works but when I try to access www.example.com/wp-login.php it nevers logs in -  it always come back to www.example.com/wp-login.php. Im going to give up, it's hard to me to debug and try to understand all these lines, and in the future if I need to change/edit it I may not be able to do it. Thanks anyway.